# JavaScript Pop up : Invoking in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I am using a simple JavaScript popup and successfully invoking it this way-

```
<a href="javascript:popup('Hello World')>Click Me</a>
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to invoke the same popup on other jQuery events. For instance

```
    $("#some_button_id").click( function() {

        javascript:popup('Hello World');

    });
```

The above method doesn't work. Any other solution?

Comment: It should work. You are probably trying to bind the event handler at a moment where the element with ID `some_button_id` does not exist yet. Also note that the label `javascript:` is of no use there (you could also write `foo:`). I recommend to [get familiar with the jQuery basics first](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Comment: @Felix Kling The ID does exists and even if I remove `javascript:`, still doesn't work

Comment: But does it exist **at the moment** you are trying to bind the event handler? I assume not. HTML is parsed from top to bottom, i.e. if you but the script *above* the element, it won't work (unless you do it correctly). That's why I recommend to read the tutorial. It states: *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), **we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready**."*. And it shows you how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - You don't need the `javascript:` part because you are not attaching javascript inline. 
But that is not the cause of the error so make sure that you wait until the DOM is ready before attaching an event handler.

```
$(function(){
    var popup = function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
    $("#some_button_id").click( function() {

        popup('Hello World');

    }); 
});
```

and of course make sure you define `popup()` somewhere

Comment: @FelixKling i always learn something new, i thought that the label would cause an error! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the `popup` function is defined on your page then you should use

```
$("#some_button_id").click( function() {
    popup('Hello World');
});
```

The `javascript:` prefix is only needed when you use javascript code directly inside your html attributes.

Comment: The label is unnecessary, but it is not the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ncQGm/. And your last sentence is not 100% correct either. `javascript:` is only needed as URI scheme in `href` attributes (or anything that takes a URL).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#some_button_id").click( function() {

        popup('Hello World');

    });
```

should work.

EDIT

this will work for sure if the id exit when the event if fired , wether or not it has been created when the the listener was added , it is called delegation :

```
$(document.body).click( function(e) {
if(e.target.getAttribute("id")=="some_button_id"){
        popup('Hello World');
}
});
```

Comment: Please see my comments on the other answers. `javascript:` is not the problem here.

Comment: well i work with the code that is given to me , i dont assume anything , if the person who wants answers wants a complete one he should provide the complete code.

Comment: Maybe this is the complete code... and even if you just consider the given code, the fact that nothing is wrong with it only lets you conclude that the problem is somewhere else, so why post an answer that does not actually change anything?